# Site on HTTPS, but images upload as HTTP, and are then broken on front end

Tags: image, https

Our site is set to use `HTTPS` in `Settings > General`. and with the following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^wp$ https://www.wascc.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, when we click `Media > Upload`, the image is returned with a `HTTP` in its URL, not `HTTPS`, and consequently the image appears as broken on the front page, due to being `mixed content`.

How can we force images to upload as `HTTPS`?

Comment: Can this be migrated to wordpress.stackexchange.com please?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing `HTTP` to `HTTPS` in the `siteurl` & `home` options in the `wp_options` MySQL database table.